# how to integrate revenucat to flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, revenuecat

i develop an horoscope and tarot card app in flutter and i'm trying to integrate an subscription plan in it and i decided to use revenuecat to help me with renewal subscription keep subs data etc. but right now flutter revenuecat tutorials are useless because they are outdated their code is not functional now and also revenuecat documentation too i searched posts here too but the one i found also outdated i really run out of options i'd appreciated if you can help me and provide some code parts or tutorial i couldnt found of some documentation